# Another Fork() program in C

Tags: c, linux, fork

So I am continuing some more problems on Fork() and found some sample code on a website called geeksforgeeks.  The following code segment:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void forkexample() 
{
    int x = 1;

    if (fork() == 0)
        printf("Child has x = %d\n", ++x);
    else
        printf("Parent has x = %d\n", --x);
}
int main()
{
    forkexample();
    return 0;
}
```

Now I can see why the solution can be either **Child has x = 2** and **Parent has x = 0** but I am having some issues trying to visualize the tree.  The big problem that I have visualizing this is that the first **if** statement is for the child process, so how would the tree look?  Here is what I have come up with in terms of a visualization of this program.

[image]

Or would the main node on Level 0 be a Child node because of the order of the **if** statement coming first (this is a possibility but the **else** statement could come first as well as it is running concurrently).

Any help?  Is this visualization correct or is there something I am missing?

Would appreciate the help , thank you.

Comment: After `fork()` function returns - you are either in the child process, or in a parent process, or there is error happened (it's not checked in that code). If `fork()` returned successfully you cannot tell anything about order - both child and parent processes continue running completely independently (unless you introduce some kind of synchronisation)

Comment: There is no order. After the fork you have **two** if-statements, one in the parent and one in the child, possibly running at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where the question is here..

The schema is good it's like this. Fork() creates a new process by duplicating the calling process. On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child. On failure, -1 is returned in the parent, no child process is created (google). You must check the return value to be sure that you're in the child process which is running independently.

Try this :

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() 
{
  pid_t p;
  int   x;

  x = 1;
  p = fork();
  printf("pid = %d\n", p);
  if (p == 0) {
    printf("Child has x = %d and pid = %d\n", ++x, p);
    sleep(1);
  } else {
    printf("Parent has x = %d and pid = %d\n", --x, p);
    sleep(1);
  }
}
```

They are executed at the same time because they are independant but the parent is primary at the ouput

Nicolas

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your response.  I understand the conditions for Fork() but I am having trouble visualizing the tree when fork is called.  In the case of the code I provided, you can see that the "child" process is the first statement called because the **if** statement is called first.  So would the node at Level0 always be a parent (even though the **else** statement is called after?) because it is in the **else** statement that the Parent process is called.  Is my visualization correct?

Comment: Lol, I was coding an example for you but it resulted in a forkbomb ahahah had to shut down everything.
I'll give you an example, going to edit my answer !

Comment: Hahaha xD no worries man.  I'll be sure to stay clear from fork bombing my machine haha.

Comment: Done! Never fork in loop xD

Comment: @Derek after returning from fork() call, the processes become independent & we can never know which one will be sceduled first. The logical order of the if & else in the parent doesn't matter (that means the code in the else branch could execute before the code in the if branche). Fork() is a tricky hack.

Comment: Nice code.  So when the first if statement is called, where fork ==0, is the copy of the code made from there or is it made from the else statement (because that's where the parent process is located)?

Comment: When you fork you duplicate the parent process so it's the same code but you're in the child process (pid = 0) as Karim said fork is tricky and there is no logical order because they are independant. But the output will display the parent first.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That's what I needed to confirm, if the parent will always be displayed first.  I can understand there being no logical order as they are running concurrently in separate processes (independent like you said).  Makes a lot more sense now, thanks for everyone who posted here!! Kudos to everyone :)

Comment: One last question actually - Are the address allocations always different in the parent vs child?  Since they are independent the address allocation spaces will always be different, correct?

Comment: Try to print there adress you'll see

Comment: Child different from parent :)

Comment: @NicolasGuerin: The indentation suggests that there are missing `{` and `}` in your `if` blocks. This code will not even compile.

Comment: @marcolz yeah sorry, I typed it directly here I forgot {} in the if else block

Answer (score 1):

No, your visualization is wrong.

After the fork you have TWO processes: Parent and Child. (PERIOD)

A single parent may spawn multiple children, and each may spawn children of their own. But after a single fork, the "tree" is two "nodes".

Not sure if you are trying to graph:

- Processes over time, then YES, you are correct, one process has become two.
- Process relationship, then NO, you should only have one parent, one child.
- Execution path, I guess... at some point fork() is called, next thing you know, you have two processes executing the if() statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Octavio.  L1 shows two nodes though being the result.  One child, and the original parent.  Is that not correct?

Comment: If your tree is representing how they "look" over time, then, yes it is correct. L0 is _before_ fork(), L1 is _after_ fork(). I think the confusion comes from having two nodes in your graphical representation, which are actually the same. Maybe I am not understanding the question.